# Setup of left and right footers in css grid wireframe

Tags: css, css-grid

How do I keep the left-footer on the left and the right-footer on the right using CSS grid?
I have been modifying the wireframe from another [codepen](https://codepen.io/mercuryworks/pen/VWBqdx) and have added left-footer and right-footer classes to use with the footer HTML5 tag and have added a .nav as well as .left-footer and .right-footer sections to the css code.

The fourth line of "grid-template-areas:" is:
"footer footer  footer  footer";

Do I need to change it to something like the following?:
"footer left-footer right-footer    footer";

If so how do I define them so the grid knows what to do with them?
Thank you.

My code pen is [here](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/NWxZQGW).

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- original source from https://codepen.io/mercuryworks/pen/VWBqdx-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Week 2 dd</title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
        Header
    </header>
  <nav class ="nav">Nav</nav>
     <main class="main">
        Main content
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        Footer
   <footer class="left-footer">
     <p>Left Footer<p></footer>
    <footer class="right-footer">
           <p> Right Footer<p></footer>       
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
    height: 120vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15rem 15rem 15rem 15rem;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header         header  header  header"
    "nav        nav     nav      nav"
        "main      main         main        main"
        "footer         footer  footer  footer";
    max-width: 66rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.header {
  max-height: 5rem;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    grid-area: header;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 1;
    }
}

.nav {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  max-height: 1rem;
    grid-area: nav;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 1;
    }
}


.main {
    grid-area: main;
    padding: 1rem;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 1;
    }
}

.aside {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 3;
        border-right: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}

.footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
    grid-area: footer;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 4;
    }
}

.left-footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
    grid-area: footer;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 4;
    }
}

.right-footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    @media (max-width: 36rem) {
        order: 4;
    }
}


// Setup
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I need to end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: If you can get rid of `.footer` element, and put both `.left-footer` and `.right-footer` inside `.wrapper` - you can try `"left-footer left-footer right-footer right-footer"`. Alternative is [subgrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid), but it is not yet supported in most browsers.

Comment: I was hoping to keep .footer. I haven't heard of subgrid but I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the main wrapping footer and put both `left-footer` and `right-footer` under the `wrapper`.

So it will be something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 120vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "nav nav nav nav" "main main main main" "left-footer left-footer right-footer right-footer";
  max-width: 66rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.header {
  max-height: 5rem;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  grid-area: header;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.nav {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  max-height: 1rem;
  grid-area: nav;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 1rem;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 3;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.left-footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: left-footer;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 4;
  }
}

.right-footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: right-footer;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 4;
  }
}

// Setup
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- original source from https://codepen.io/mercuryworks/pen/VWBqdx-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Week 2 dd</title>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">Nav</nav>
    <main class="main">
      Main content
    </main>
    <footer class="left-footer">
      <p>Left Footer
        <p>
    </footer>
    <footer class="right-footer">
      <p> Right Footer
        <p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

So as you update your question the above answer should be something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 120vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "nav nav nav nav" "main main main main" "left-footer right-footer right-footer right-footer";
  max-width: 66rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.header {
  max-height: 5rem;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  grid-area: header;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.nav {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  max-height: 1rem;
  grid-area: nav;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 1rem;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 3;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.left-footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: left-footer;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 4;
  }
}

.right-footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: right-footer;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  @media (max-width: 36rem) {
    order: 4;
  }
}

// Setup
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- original source from https://codepen.io/mercuryworks/pen/VWBqdx-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Week 2 dd</title>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">Nav</nav>
    <main class="main">
      Main content
    </main>
    <footer class="left-footer">
      <p>Left Footer
        <p>
    </footer>
    <footer class="right-footer">
      <p> Right Footer
        <p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code,To Setup of left and right footers in css grid wireframe

Html code:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<footer>
  <!-- Footer main -->
  <section class="ft-main">
    <div class="ft-main-item">
      <h2 class="ft-title">About</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ft-main-item">
      <h2 class="ft-title">Resources</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">eBooks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Webinars</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ft-main-item">
      <h2 class="ft-title">Contact</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ft-main-item">
      <h2 class="ft-title">Stay Updated</h2>
      <p>Subscribe to our newsletter to get our latest news.</p>
      <form>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer social -->
  <section class="ft-social">
    <ul class="ft-social-list">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer legal -->
  <section class="ft-legal">
    <ul class="ft-legal-list">
      <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li>&copy; 2019 Copyright Nowrap Inc.</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Css code:

```
/* Generic styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #bbb;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ft-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}
/* Sticks footer to bottom */
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
}
/* Footer main */
.ft-main {
  padding: 1.25rem 1.875rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 29.8125rem /* 477px */) {
  .ft-main {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 77.5rem /* 1240px */) {
  .ft-main {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}
.ft-main-item {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 12.5rem;
}

/* Footer main | Newsletter form */
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
input[type="email"] {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #00d188;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem 0.9375rem;
  margin-top: 0.3125rem;
}
/* Footer social */
.ft-social {
  padding: 0 1.875rem 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 1px #777 solid;
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}
.ft-social-list li {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
/* Footer legal */
.ft-legal {
  padding: 0.9375rem 1.875rem;
  background-color: #333;
}
.ft-legal-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ft-legal-list li {
  margin: 0.125rem 0.625rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* one before the last child */
.ft-legal-list li:nth-last-child(2) {
    flex: 1;
}
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Thank you.